# Aligning The whole website to right from left -translate from english to hebrew

Tags: php, css, position, translate

My website is in English and is written from left to right. Translate the site into any language which is written from left to right it's not a problem - just go to the code and change the text. The problem that I want to translate it into Hebrew that are written from right to left. I translated the website texts (buttons and menu), the problem that the structure of the site is left to right. What is the easiest way to fix this? When I tried to change the code to move the placement of things I got into trouble a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<body style="direction: rtl">
    [..contents...]
</body>
```

Useful links: 
http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html

Comment: After that further changes to the site's CSS would very likely be needed, to fix all right/left definitions such as floats, margins, absolute positions etc.

Comment: Talya you speak hebrew ?

Comment: Yes I do speak Hebrew

Comment: You have email that we can talk and you help me llitle ? ( please - בבקשה עשי טובה :))

Comment: Not sure how comfortable I am with this, but leave your address and I'll message you.